# a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session + nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am using ninject mvc 3 and nhibernate and I get this error when I try to do an update and I don't understand why.

```
NHibernate.NonUniqueObjectException was unhandled by user code
  Message=a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: e1a7bd1f-fe1d-4c2e-a459-9fcb0106ad1d, of entity: Card
  Source=NHibernate
  EntityName=Card
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.CheckUniqueness(EntityKey key, Object obj)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.PerformUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event, Object entity, IEntityPersister persister)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsDetached(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultUpdateEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Update(Object obj)
       at CCRecomendator.Framework.Data.Repository.NhibernateRepo.Update[T](T entity) in NhibernateRepo.cs:line 33
       at CardService.EditCard(Card card, IList`1 rewardTiersToUseAfterCap) in CardService.cs:line 108
       at 
   CardController.EditCbCreditCard(CbCreditCardFrmVm vm) in CardController.cs:line 505
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

I can't figure out why it would be still be in the nhibernate session. I have one web request that gets the card and binds it to VM.

It then displays on the page. I then have a save method that gets called and I try to bind VM to a Card Domain then try to update it this is when I get the above error.

These are 2 different calls though and the session should be disposed off.

```
  Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider<NhibernateSessionFactoryProvider>().InSingletonScope();
            Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InRequestScope();
```

I am not sure if I need to call another dispose or what.

I use the unit of work so I added a dispose method but not sure when I should call it and if this will even solve my problem

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        private ITransaction transaction;
        private readonly ISession session;

        public UnitOfWork(ISession session)
        {
            this.session = session;
            session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts a transaction with the database. Uses IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        /// </summary>
        public void BeginTransaction()
        {
            transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// starts a transaction with the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="level">IsolationLevel the transaction should run in.</param>
        public void BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel level)
        {
            transaction = session.BeginTransaction(level);
        }

        private bool IsTransactionActive()
        {
            return transaction.IsActive;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Commits the transaction and writes to the database.
        /// </summary>
        public void Commit()
        {
            // make sure a transaction was started before we try to commit.
            if (!IsTransactionActive())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Oops! We don't have an active transaction. Did a rollback occur before this commit was triggered: "
                                                            + transaction.WasRolledBack + " did a commit happen before this commit: " + transaction.WasCommitted);
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rollback any writes to the databases.
        /// </summary>
        public void Rollback()
        {
            if (IsTransactionActive())
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose() // don't know where to call this to see if it will solve my problem
        {
            if (session.IsOpen)
            {
                session.Close();
            }

        }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditCbCard(CbCardFrmVm vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Card card = new Card
        {
            Id = vm.Id, // id of the record in the database
            Country = countryService.LoadCountryById(vm.SelectedCountry)
        };

        CardService.EditCard(card, rewardTiersToUseAfterCap);

    }

    ModelStateValidationWrapper wrapper = ConvertTo.ModelStateValidationWrapper(creditCardService.ValidationDictionary, ModelState);
    return Json(wrapper);
}

  public void EditCard(Card card, IList<string> rewardTiersToUseAfterCap)
    {
        try
        {
            unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();

            nhibernateRepo.Update(creditCard);

            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
        catch (ADOException ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            ValidationDictionary.AddError("DbError", ExceptionMsgs.DbError);
            unitOfWork.Rollback();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            ValidationDictionary.AddError("DbError", ExceptionMsgs.DbError);
            unitOfWork.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

Anyone see why it would think it is in the same session.

Comment: check `EditCard(Card --->card<--- ...` and below `nhibernateRepo.Update(--->creditCard<---);` seems like different ones? Also you create a new object `Card card = new Card` with the already used ID, does it help?

Comment: They are the same thing. I shortened names down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you dispose the session it would be incorrect to create a new card to update state. Instead of

```
Card card = new Card
{
    Id = vm.Id, // id of the record in the database
    Country = countryService.LoadCountryById(vm.SelectedCountry)
};
```

use

```
Card card = unitOfWork.Get<Card>(vm.Id)
card.Country = countryService.LoadCountryById(vm.SelectedCountry);
```

to get the correct state. It will give you the cached instance when available without hitting the Database

Comment: why is it incorrect? I tired .Get and .Load with the nhibernate profile and it does hit the database. So why would this be better than creating a new object and filling in the id's. I would think this would result into one database call not 2(as you still will have to call a commit to update the changes). What case would you use Update() then?

Comment: AFAIK Update should also hit the database to know which properties have changed. If you create a new card object would you not lose all other properties except the one you set?

Comment: I am not sure what would happen in that case. In my scenario though every option could change so I have to post everything to the db. I guess maybe it might have to update less if I get the actual object. I don't think I can use .Get or .Load as I would need to eager load multiple tables for instance as you can see Country is another table so would that not have to loaded?

Comment: country is a reference which is lazyloaded with the id then changed hence no need to load it to replace the reference

Comment: but then I would need do something like Country = new Country{ Id = newId} to update The Card to the new country. I have other relationships(not shown) that I might need to update their values. They would be lazy loaded then by the Get Or Load correct?

Comment: `countryService.LoadCountryById(vm.SelectedCountry)` is just fine. The other association would be loaded when accessed which IMO is needed to see what changes, otherwise NH couldn't differenciate between `.Name = null` and Name not changed

Comment: How about in this case? I have another relationship(cards has many rewards). The user while editing can "add" even more rewards. Say they set originally 5 rewards and now updated those 5 rewards and added another 3 rewards. So in this case a new record maybe created(or even deleted for that matter). Values in the existing records might change(think name or something like that). If I load/get for Card then got those rewards from Card they would be lazy loaded correct? Would I still be doing an update or would I have to delete all the rewards and then recreate them all?

Comment: it depends, if all you did was adding new rewards NH doesnt have to load all the existing rewards and will just issue inserts. if you changed them you already loaded them so no problem